# Loop shows only the last instance of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm trying to generate HTML content by looping through an array and inputting data into my HTML string.

I've tried using the following answer from Stack Overflow (with no luck): 
[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example/19323214#19323214)

Other answer's I have looked at are too complex for what I want to do.

Here is my original code:

```
    var staticOptions = [
  {
    name : "option1",
    id : "option1",
    img : "img/extras/360-chasis.jpg"
  },
  {
    name : "option2",
    id : "option2",
    img : "img/extras/lifing-eye.jpg"
  },
  {
    name : "option3",
    id : "option3",
    img : "img/extras/360-window.jpg"
  },
  {
    name : "option4",
    id : "option4",
    img : "img/extras/led-flood-light.jpg"
  },
  {
    name : "option5",
    id : "option5",
    img : "img/extras/360-canteen-light.jpg"
  }
];

for (var i = 0; i < staticOptions.length; i++ ) {
  var optionHtml = '<div class="form-check width30">'
                + '<label class="form-check-label" for="'
                + staticOptions[i].id
                + '">'
                + '<input class="form-check-input" id="'
                + staticOptions[i].id
                + '" type="checkbox">'
                + staticOptions[i].name
                + '<!--        <span class="indiv-price">£300</span>-->'
                + '</label>'
                + '  </div>'
                + '<div class="info-img hide"><img src="'
                + staticOptions[i].img
                + '"></div>';

  $("#bodyOptions").html(optionHtml);

};
```

This code as it stands only outputs the last item of my array. However, if I use the alert method to output the html it loops through all five objects in my array as expected.

Reading the top vote answer of the question above mentions "closures" I tried to adapt that answer to my code but it does not output anything (No errors showing either):

```
function createfunc(i) {
    return function() { 

      var optionHtml = '<div class="form-check width30">'
                + '<label class="form-check-label" for="'
                + [i].id
                + '">'
                + '<input class="form-check-input" id="'
                + [i].id
                + '" type="checkbox">'
                + [i].name
                + '<!--        <span class="indiv-price">£300</span>-->'
                + '</label>'
                + '  </div>'
                + '<div class="info-img hide"><img src="'
                + [i].img
                + '"></div>';

    $("#bodyOptions").html(optionHtml);

    };
}

for (var i = 0; i < staticOptions.length; i++) {
    staticOptions[i] = createfunc(i);
}
```

In summary, all I want to do is create five pieces of HTML code which inputs the data for each instance from the array and write it in HTML to the page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're overwriting the content of `#bodyOptions` on each round of the loop...

Comment: Well yeah... you are using `html(...)` which completely erases the HTML before so your first iteration's HTML is gone when the second iteration is added

Comment: wow! How did I not see that! Thanks

Comment: `.append();`  or `.prepend();`

Comment: First, its bad practice to append/modify DOM in loop. You should try to generate complete HTMLString and then process it. In your first attempt, replace `optionHtml = ` to `optionHtml += `, and outside loop, do `$("#bodyOptions").html(optionHtml);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#bodyOptions").html($("#bodyOptions").html() + optionHtml);
```

Seems like you are replacing whole `#bodyOptions` HTML with the new option, so what you need to do is add to what it contains already.

Comment: Happy to be helpful :)

Comment: Note, you should create HTML string and perform a bulk operation, instead of looping and changing again and again. DOM manipulation is very expensive operation in JS.